# Does an anchor tag come before the query string or after?

Tags: html, query

I am unclear if an anchor tag should come before a query string or after.

http://www.domain.com/search?query=hello#name

or

http://www.domain.com/search#name?query=hello

Or does it matter?

Comment: Test it. Only one of them works, so it does matter. When I tried anchor first then it thinks the ? is part of the "#" fragment and thus doesn't hop to the right anchor (since there isn't one that has ? in its name...) and probably wouldn't include any info if I checked for the query string in PHP. The last one I haven't tested.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Best practice is to append the named anchor at the end. The technical name is a fragment identifier, and the syntax is in RFC 3986.

The RFC section is here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.1

> relative-ref  = relative-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) actually covers it well:

> The fragment identifier introduced by a hash mark # is the optional last part of a URL for a document

Comment: Cheers @iivel!  [Section 3](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3) was more helpful for me (section-4.1 seems specific to relative URIs) as I debated this with someone.

Comment: What about webserver, does it need to handle it during serving page ?

Comment: @raypixar URL fragments are not sent to the server